# Category param redirect to post type archive

Tags: categories, query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to filter categories by **post type**.

*e.g*: the following URI will retrieve all `post` from the category `news`.

> https://example.com/category/news/?post_type=post.

Here is how I'm updating the main query:

```php
function gpc_filter_categories( WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
        $get = esc_sql( $_GET['post_type'] );
        $query->set( 'post_type', $get );
    }

    return $query;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gpc_filter_categories' );
```

This actually work great.

But here is the problem: it doesn't work with `custom post type`.
Let's say I've a post type named `movie`.

When accessing the following URI, the `archive.php` template is used instead of `category.php`.

> https://example.com/category/news/?post_type=movie.

Comment: You can use the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) or [`archive_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/archive_template/) hook to force WordPress to use the `category.php` template.

Comment: @SallyCJ Using `template_include` worked, thank you.
Just to know, is this behavior a bug or is it normal? I mean `is_category()` should not return *true* if `category.php` is not loaded...

Comment: `is_category()` returns true when the request URL has the format like so: `example.com/category/some/category` (the key is the `/category/`). And the template used is based on `is_category()` - i.e. it's the conditional/query that determines the template and not the other way round. You should also know that if the theme doesn't have a `category.php` template, then the category archive would default to using the `archive.php` template (for all post types).